# footer not staying on bottom of page

Tags: html, css, footer

i grabbed a template from themeforest and modded it. all works well, except, on some pages, the footer isn't sticking at the bottom of the page. i've messed w/ the css a bit, but haven't been able to get it stick. i'm still learning html/css so wanted some help in reviewing it to make sure i don't have any mistakes in my html. i haven't modded the css from the initial template. i did some, but reverted them before the post, as they were attempts at getting the footer to stick.

here is a link to the site > http://capitalcrestoration.com/build/

Comment: It would be best to put these in pages to demo, in addition to the pastebin's w/ code.

Comment: See under the "Related" at the bottom right!

Comment: @jawad  i should have mentioned i've tried most everything i've found here, yet nothing has helped. one solution will keep it at the bottom but i lose my background or spacing. others will keep background at the bottom but not the links. thanks for the suggestion though...

Comment: @user700070 i posted the actual site link.

Comment: When I run into formatting errors like this I find it easy to recode some parts.

Answer (score 1):

I think from your question you are asking how to make the footer appear at the bottom of the window at all times.

To do this you just need to change the CSS rule for `#subfooter-wrapper`:

```
#subfooter-wrapper {
    background: url("images/sub_footer_bg.jpg") repeat-x scroll 0 0 transparent;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

Comment: tried this, but that keeps the footer on top that needs to be scrolled. this won't work for what i need. thanks though. will come in handy on another page.

Comment: @bdizzle I am not sure I understand your question then. On every page I looked at your footer is at the bottom. Which page on the site shows the problem and what browser are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You could try giving [CSSStickyFooter](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/) a shot.

You need to do something with your CSS to position the footer element at the bottom of the window.  Otherwise it's just a block element that will be directly under it's sibling.

Comment: i've tried this way, but i don't understand the css well enough to make this. i see some mains already together, but don't understand how to integrate this into the current template.

Answer (score 0):

Try placing div id="subfooter-wrapper" just before the closing tag of the wrapper, and using position:absolute; bottom: 0;

Comment: Please properly format your code.  Use ` on each side or highlight the code and click the code formatting button.